# Dealing with datetime time overnight

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of `datetime.time()` ranges obtained from different days, sorted by `init`, and I need to get an output taking into consideration overlapping times. For example,

```
[{'init': datetime.time(10,0,0), 'end': datetime.time(12,0,0)},
 {'init': datetime.time(11,0,0), 'end': datetime.time(12,30,0)},
 {'init': datetime.time(22,0,0), 'end': datetime.time(4,30,0)},
 {'init': datetime.time(23,0,0), 'end': datetime.time(0,30,0)}]
```

The output should be:

```
[{{'init': datetime.time(10,0,0), 'end': datetime.time(12,30,0)},
 {'init': datetime.time(22,0,0), 'end': datetime.time(4,30,0)}
```

To do so, I iterate through each item in the list, updating the init and end values depending on whether the criteria is met (i.e. the item fully or partially overlaps with the previous one).

```
x, y = range_list[0]['init'], range_list[0]['end']
for range in range_list:
    if range['init'] <= y:
        if range['end'] > y:
            y = range['end']
    else:
        print(x, y)
        x = range['init']
        y = range['end']
```

However, following this logic I can't work with overnight ranges, because for example, `22:00:00` is not less than `04:30:00`.

As I control the input data, I thought on returning the list with full `datetime` objects or `timestamp`, like

```
[{'init': datetime.time(2019,1,12,10,0,0), 'end': datetime.time(2019,1,12,12,0,0)},
 {'init': datetime.time(2019,1,13,11,0,0), 'end': datetime.time(2019,1,13,12,30,0)},
 {'init': datetime.time(2019,1,14,22,0,0), 'end': datetime.time(2019,1,15,4,30,0)},
 {'init': datetime.time(2019,1,16,23,0,0), 'end': datetime.time(2019,1,17,0,30,0)}]
```

however, this will not work because every item would be higher than the previous one due to the date.

So, how could I solve this issue?

TL;DR; how to deal with time ranges overnight if using a full `datetime` or `timestamp` is not an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by actually using `datetime`, but on a fixed date.

Given an input data like:

```
ranges = [{'init': datetime.time(10,0,0), 'end': datetime.time(12,0,0)},
          {'init': datetime.time(11,0,0), 'end': datetime.time(12,30,0)},
          {'init': datetime.time(22,0,0), 'end': datetime.time(4,30,0)},
          {'init': datetime.time(23,0,0), 'end': datetime.time(0,30,0)}]
```

I iterate over each item, transforming them to full `datetime` objects in which the date part is `1970-01-01`. If `init` is greater than `end`, the I add one day to `end` and that's it. Now I can work with overnight time ranges without any issues.

```
for range in ranges:
    range['init'] = datetime.combine(datetime(1970, 1, 1), range['init'])
    range['end'] = datetime.combine(datetime(1970, 1, 1), range['end'])
    if range['init'] > range['end']:
        range['end'] = range['end'].replace(day=2)
```

@martineau's answer does not address the point of the question. It helps to have a cleaner code, but did not address the issue which was dealing with time ranges over night when `datetime` was not an option (it ended up being though, but not the real one)

Answer (score 0):

I've changed my mind (and answer) and now think you should just define  make your own data-structure to hold the times in your dictionaries. With that you can easily adjust the end-time to be relative to the same day as the init-time.

In the code below the range_list has the same values in it as shown in your question, so that is adjusted by changing the end-times as needed.

After adjustment, `range_list` contains:

```
[{'init': Timestamp(10, 0, 0), 'end': Timestamp(12, 0, 0)}
 {'init': Timestamp(11, 0, 0), 'end': Timestamp(12,30, 0)}
 {'init': Timestamp(22, 0, 0), 'end': Timestamp(28,30, 0)}
 {'init': Timestamp(23, 0, 0), 'end': Timestamp(24,30, 0)}]
```

Since you control the input data, it might be better to just create them in the needed format.

```
from collections import namedtuple
from pprint import pprint, pformat


class Timestamp(namedtuple('Timestamp', 'h,m,s')):
    def __repr__(self):
        classname = self.__class__.__name__
        return '{}({:2},{:2},{:2})'.format(classname, self.h, self.m, self.s)


range_list = [{'init': Timestamp(10,0,0), 'end': Timestamp(12,0,0)},
              {'init': Timestamp(11,0,0), 'end': Timestamp(12,30,0)},
              {'init': Timestamp(22,0,0), 'end': Timestamp(4,30,0)},
              {'init': Timestamp(23,0,0), 'end': Timestamp(0,30,0)}]

# Adjust end times.
for i, interval in enumerate(range_list):
    init, end = interval['init'], interval['end']
    range_list[i] = {'init': init,
                     'end' : Timestamp(end.h+24 if end.h < init.h else end.h,
                             end.m, end.s)}

def merge(intervals):
    merged = []
    x, y = intervals[0]['init'], intervals[0]['end']
    for interval in intervals:
        if interval['init'] <= y:
            if interval['end'] > y:
                y = interval['end']
        else:
            merged.append({'init': x, 'end': y})
            x = interval['init']
            y = interval['end']
    merged.append({'init': x, 'end': y})
    return merged


print(merge(range_list))
```

Output:

```
[{'init': Timestamp(10, 0, 0), 'end': Timestamp(12,30, 0)},
 {'init': Timestamp(22, 0, 0), 'end': Timestamp(28,30, 0)}]
```

Comment: the main issue is still present though. For example, any interval can't overlap other interval because of the different `day`

Comment: you are right that it should work, however, you missed something in my question: *obtained from different days*, means that following using `datetime`, today's time will always be greater than yesterday's time, and therefore, will never overlap, which is not correct.